# how to eliminate specific columns by column name

Tags: r, performance, subset

I have a data set `df` and I have 300 columns. I also have a vector `names` which is a vector of characters. I'm trying to eliminate the columns that match the characters in `names`. I tried

```
    > head(names)
[1] "X749.-4" "X339"    "X449"    "X486"    "X300"    "X301" 
    real.final<-df[-names]
    Error in -names : invalid argument to unary operator
```

Would there be a way to remove the columns mentioned in the `names`?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `setdiff` instead. Here's an example:

```
## This is head(names)
x <- c("X749.-4", "X339", "X449", "X486", "X300", "X301")

## Imagine this is names(df)
y <- c(letters[1:2], x, LETTERS[1:2])

setdiff(y, x)
# [1] "a" "b" "A" "B"

## So, you could try:
df[, setdiff(y, x)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The negation operator "-" will not work with character arguments passed as arguments to "[". You need to either use a lgocal vector with "!" as illustrated by user2568648, or you need to convert the character vector into numeric vector with `grep`:

```
#Failed attemtpt : real.final <- df[-grep(names, names(df) )]
```

Perhaps:

```
real.final <- df[ -as.vector(sapply(names[1], grep, x=c(names,names)))]
```

Another error:

```
real.final <- subset( df, select=-names)
Error in -"Result" : invalid argument to unary operator
```

Success with:

```
 subset(df, select=-which(names(df) %in% names))
```

I don't like to use `-which()` because it will bite you if there are no "hits", but it's probably safe as an argument to subset.

Comment: Thank you. I get the error for grep(names, names(df) )] argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used. I don't follow this error message.

Comment: It was only using the first item in names and giving a warning. I should have sent the items one at a time to `grep`.

Comment: Thank you. The last code did not work, and I think it's because names is a character vector, not integer. The error was the same.

Comment: Huh, your right. If you use use a unquoted tokens, it does succeed but that's not of much use to you. This works: `subset(df, select=-which(names(df) %in% names))`

Answer (score -1):

Would this work? [NO - see comment from Dwin below for correction]

```
    subset.df<-subset(df, !(colnames(df) %in% names))
```

Comment: I thought it would work, but it deleted the observations, not the columns (variables). I don't think I follow.

Comment: Should have been been sent to the select argument for subset. Or just used with `df[ , !(colnames(df) %in% names) ]`

Answer (score -1):

You can use the which function. For example to drop the columns named "X749.-4" and "X486":

```
df <- df[ , -which(names(df) %in% c("X749.-4", "X486"))]
```

Comment: Although it did not drop all of the variables, I think it worked. Thank you!

Comment: I have one more question though, I did df <- df[ , -which(names(df) %in% names)] and this did not eliminate ALL of the variables in names. I'm sure that variables in the vector names are all in the data frame df, and I'm trying to figure out what possibly went wrong.

Comment: I just gave the example to delete the two columns named "X749.-4" and "X486" (see updated answer), you can delete all of them as follows: `df <- df[ , -which(names(df) %in% c("X749.-4" "X339"    "X449"    "X486"    "X300"    "X301"))]`

Comment: Ps: if you like an answer that solves your question you can vote for it by clicking on the left of the answer to help show the question has been answered

Comment: Why did my answer get a -1?? It is a proper and working answer to the question!

Comment: @seungyeon can you please remove the -1? It disables me to contribute on stackoverflow while you semed to like my answer!